# AWS Api Gateway and Cognito cause CORS errors

Tags: amazon-web-services, cors, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito

I don't know how to start, I'm struggling with CORS errors when using the API gateway with Cognito as an authorizer. I have spent a lot of time on it and I believe I have read the whole internet to figure out what is going on and wrong.
So let's start with a simple example. My lambda:

```
import json
def handler(event, context):
    print('Lambda is here')
    return dict(
        statusCode=200,
        headers={
            'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': '*',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': '*',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': 'true',
        },
        body=json.dumps({'message': 'lambda works'})
    )
```

HTML code for testing CORS and authorization:

```
<head>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
        axios.get(
            "api_gateway_url",
        )
        .then(response =>alert(response.data.message))
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error)
            alert("ERROR")
        })
</script>
</body>
```

For API gateway without authentication, the response is:
[image]

For API gateway with authentication, the response is:
[image]
[image]

The response code depends on the configuration of the API gateway. I have changed everything that I can many many times, I was testing it setting by setting and nothing helps me. I have added CORS headers in places like Method Response, Integration Response, and Gateway Responses, under Enable CORS configuration. Depending on the configuration I have a few status codes 401, 403, and 500 and always CORS error occurs.
While testing the requests haven't touched the lambda, so the above errors weren't the results of lambda execution.

I have tested it by deploying it with CDK I created an example code you can also try in your local environment. The link to the code https://gitlab.com/magnus250/cognito-api-gateway-cdk-problems/

Comment: could you post a screenshot of `Response Headers` of preflight request? what do you get as headers in that?

Comment: I've answered a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72762595/cors-error-trying-to-access-api-gateway-that-triggers-a-lambda-function-from-nex/72802597#72802597.  The error message you posted is very specific as to what is wrong.  The "Preflight" refers to the Options method within API Gateway.  If using CORS, in addition to the Get method, you Need an Options method on your APIGW endpoint.  In the Integration Response for the Options method, you need to add the header for "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" and set it to '*' (or a specific domain).

Comment: Thank you guys, I added a final answer to my question.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I have finally solved my problem. @sampath-dilhan @chris-smith thank You. So let me describe how I achieved it.

I think the whole API gateway is bugged and you never know what exactly you have configured. The base development of the API gateway was provided by CDK and then I try different configurations to enable CORS from the console. I read the whole internet about CORS configuration and I tried to use this knowledge to enable CORS, always re-deploying API and waiting for some time until testing.

Below I put the CDK configuration, that works for me. For people who struggle with problems, I recommend always destroying your stack and re-deploy it in a clean environment, because as I already mentioned I believe that API Gateway is bugged. The code also has domain and certificate definitions.

```
    def create_api_gateway(
        self,
        prefix: str,
        domain: str,
        certificate_arn: str,
        cognito_user_pool_arn: str,
        handler: _lambda.Function,
    ) -> None:
        base_api = apigateway.RestApi(
            self,
            f"{prefix}-authorized-rest-api",
            deploy_options=apigateway.StageOptions(
                throttling_burst_limit=100,
                throttling_rate_limit=100,
                caching_enabled=False,
                cache_cluster_enabled=False,
            ),
            default_cors_preflight_options=apigateway.CorsOptions(
                allow_headers=[
                    "Content-Type",
                    "X-Amz-Date",
                    "Authorization",
                    "X-Api-Key",
                ],
                allow_methods=["*"],
                allow_credentials=True,
                allow_origins=["*"],
            ),
            domain_name=apigateway.DomainNameOptions(
                certificate=certificatemanager.Certificate.from_certificate_arn(
                    self,
                    f"{prefix}-certificate",
                    certificate_arn=certificate_arn,
                ),
                domain_name=f"api.{domain}",
                endpoint_type=apigateway.EndpointType.EDGE,
            ),
        )
        response_types = [
            apigateway.ResponseType.DEFAULT_4_XX,
            apigateway.ResponseType.DEFAULT_5_XX,
        ]
        for response_type in response_types:
            base_api.add_gateway_response(
                f"{prefix}-api-gateway-{response_type.response_type}",
                type=response_type,
                response_headers={
                    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "'*'",
                    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "'*'",
                    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "'*'",
                    "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": "'true'",
                },
            )

        user_pool = cognito.UserPool.from_user_pool_arn(
            self, f"{prefix}-user-pool", user_pool_arn=cognito_user_pool_arn
        )
        authorizer = apigateway.CognitoUserPoolsAuthorizer(
            self,
            f"{prefix}-authorizer",
            authorizer_name=f"{prefix}-authorizer",
            cognito_user_pools=[user_pool],
        )

        get_widgets_integration = apigateway.LambdaIntegration(handler)
        resource = base_api.root.add_resource("{proxy+}")
        resource.add_method(
            "ANY",
            get_widgets_integration,
            authorizer=authorizer,
        )

        cdk.CfnOutput(self, f"{prefix}-api-url", value=base_api.url)

        zone = route53.HostedZone.from_lookup(self, f"{prefix}-hosted-zone", domain_name=domain)
        route53.ARecord(
            self,
            f"{prefix}-dns-record",
            record_name="api",
            zone=zone,
            target=route53.RecordTarget.from_alias(route53_targets.ApiGateway(base_api)),
        )
```